# Array Formula return by Excel Custom Function

Tags: javascript, office-js, custom-functions-excel

I want to return multiple values or array formula without making range selection in excel through the function.

```
# excel custom function 
async function add(first, second) {
    try {

        Excel.run(async context => {
            # selecting active worksheet
            const worksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet(); 


            # selecting range
            const range = worksheet.getRangeByIndexes(0, 0, 1, 4); 


            # set values for selected range
            range.values = [[1, 2, 3, 4]]; 

            return context.sync();
        });
    } 
    catch(err) {
        return err.message;
    }
}

# mapping function with key
CustomFunctions.associate("ADD", add);
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting this question. Currently to enable what you're asking for requires *Excel Dynamic Arrays* to be enabled. This feature is still in **preview**, and you can start testing against that by joining the Insiders Channel (on Windows and Mac).

1. Join the Office 365 Developer program if you need a tenant: https://aka.ms/O365DevProgram.
2. Get a tenant and once setup, click Install Software to download Office (if needed)
3. Look at insiders.office.com to follow instructions on how to switch channels.
4. Launch Excel and try this formula "=MUNIT(10)"
5. If it returns a 10x10 array, you are on insiders channel.
6. Once on the insiders channel, you can just return that array from your function, i..e `return [[1, 2, 3, 4]];` and Excel would dynamically spill or return an #SPILL! error if it was about to overlap certain values.